# POI: Using an Excel template that has conditional formatting

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I'm new to using Apache Poi.
I had some questions about using an existing xlsx file as a template when it has conditional formatting.

The template file opens with no errors. I can enter data into it manually and the conditional formatting works by highlighting columns and changing fonts for specific cells in the spreadsheet.

I am using Poi to add data to the file.

I open the template add data to the appropriate cells, save the file as a new file.

```
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xlsTemplate);

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(inputStream);

    var tmpSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowCount = tmpStartRow;

    for(var tmpRow : tmpList) {

        Row row = tmpSheet.getRow(rowCount++);

        int columnCount = tmpStartCol;

        var tmpMap = tmpRow.objectToMap();

        int x = columnCount;
        for(var entry : tmpMap.entrySet()) {

            Cell cell = row.getCell(x);

            var value = "";
            if(entry.getValue() != null)
                value = (String)entry.getValue();

            try {
                var dblVal = Double.valueOf(value);
                cell.setCellValue(dblVal);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                cell.setCellValue(value);
            }
            x++;
        }
    }

    var evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    evaluator.evaluateAll();
    workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

    inputStream.close();        

    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(xlsFileName)) {
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        workbook.close();
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I open the new file, Excel does not give any errors.

After reviewing the worksheet, the cells have data in the appropriate fields, but the formatting from the template has not been set.

When I click on "Manage Rules" in the conditional formatting section, I see the rules are still there.

When I click on a cell in the spreadsheet and click on the formula bar and then click away, the conditional formatting gets triggered.

How do I get Poi to handle the conditional formatting for me? Do I need to modify the conditional formatting even though it already exists in the template?

Thanks in advance for your help..

SA

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for responding - I'm on the latest version (4.1.2).

Comment: The issue you are describing is not reproducible for me. It works properly for me using multiple kinds of `Excel` templates. So it must be an issue with your template. Can you upload the template so we can have a look?

Comment: @AxelRichter After your comment, I went back and looked at the rules. It turns out I was using empty strings instead of NULL for certain values and it was causing the rules not to work. I think I got it working now. Thanks,